# C++ calculate difference between two elements in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, element, difference

I have a 2 vectors of size 4 to store coordinates of a shape (square/rectangle). 1st vector is for x and 2nd for y. To find out the area of the shape, I need the difference in their length. How do I find the difference between 2 elements within the same vector? Using square as an example:

```
vector<int> x(4);
vector<int> y(4);

double Square::computeArea()
{
    int length;
    double area;

    if (x[0] == x[1]) //x coordinates are the same
    {
        length = y[0] - y[1]; //difference in y coordinates to find the length, need help here
    }
    else if (x[1] == x[2]
    {
        length = y[1] - y[2];
    }
    else if ... //repeat

    area = length * length;
    if (area < 0) { area = -area; }
    setArea(area)
    return area;
}
```

Comment: Why would you do this?  Why not make a `point` `struct` that holds the x and y for each point?

Comment: @user2970916 Use a for loop for x.size()? can you show me how to go about doing this because i'm new to programming

Comment: @NathanOliver storing it as {x1y1, x2y2 ....}? i also need the points for finding points within the shape and on the shape..

Comment: If you consider only rectangles or square you don't even need 4 points.

Comment: @Bob__ actually there is another class for cross. so i need to have a parent class and 3 child classes.

Comment: And all your shapes are parallel to the axis?

Comment: what formula are you using exactly to compute the area of your shape?

Comment: @Bob__ yes all shapes will be aligned with the axis.

Comment: @ARG for square length*length, rectangle length*breath

Comment: Search the internet for "distance formula point".  This will show how to calculate the distance between to points.

Answer (score 1):

If your rectangle has edges which are parallel to the axis, and the points are ordered clockwise (or counterclockwise), you can simply use the first and third element of the arrays:

```
int yedge, xedge;

xedge = abs(x[0] - x[2]);

if ( xedge == 0 ) //beware, this check works well only for ints!
     return area = 0.0;
else yedge = abs(y[0] - y[2]);

return area = xedge * yedge;
```

If you have more general convex quadrilaterals use something like this:

```
int dx20 = x[2] - x[0];
int dy10 = y[1] - y[0];
int dy20 = y[2] - y[0];
int dx10 = x[1] - x[0];
int dy30 = y[3] - y[0];
int dx30 = x[3] - x[0];

area = 0.5*abs(dx20*dy10-dy20*dx10);
area += 0.5*abs(dx20*dy30-dy20*dx30);
```

Comment: You are using array right? How about in the case of vectors?

Comment: You can use [] to access to the element of vectors, but why do you use int for the coordinates?

Comment: @Bob__ The question uses int as coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of C++ and OOP is that you can think more in terms of the problem than how to program it.

If I were in your place I would use std::pair to save the coordinates.

And have a class representing the rectangle.

I am using the distance between point 1 and 2 as length, and point 1 and 4 as width. It may not be the correct approach in all cases but it should show you have to go about programming your function.

```
using namespace std;

class Rectangle // Class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle(vector<pair<double, double>> neWcoordinates);
    double computeArea();

private:
    vector<pair<double, double>> coordinates; 
};

double Rectangle::computeArea()
{
    double length = sqrt(pow(coordinates[0].first-coordinates[1].first,2)+pow(coordinates[0].second-coordinates[1].second,2)
        );
    double width = sqrt(pow(coordinates[0].first-coordinates[3].first,2)+pow(coordinates[0].second-coordinates[3].second,2));
    return length*width;
}
```

Comment: You missed the exponent in the pow() functions, I guess. Besides, the OP claims all of the shapes are parallel to the axis...

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the exponent, as for being parallel to the axis, this should work for that too, although one can simplify the formula taking that into account.